# Compute the distribution function of the random variable $Y:=-\ln(F(X))$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm trying to prove this result:

> If $X$ is a continuous random variable with distribution function $F$, where $F$ is strictly increasing function, then  find the distribution function of the random variable $Y:=-\ln(F(X))$.

This is my attempt:

$G(Y)=Pr(Y\leq y)=Pr(-\ln(F(X))\leq y)=1-Pr(F(X)\leq e^{-y})$

Now, given that $F$ is continuous and monotonic it's invertible and its inverse is also increasing. Then

$G(Y)=1-Pr(x\leq F^{-1}(e^{-y}))=1-F_X(F^{-1}(e^{-y}))$.

However, I'm completely sure it is not correct. I'd appreciate some hints, thanks.

Comment: You confused $F$ with the cumulative distribution function $F_X$.

Comment: You are correct! Always trust yourself!

Comment: @xyzzyz I just fixed that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation is correct because $U=F(X)$ has uniform distribution:
$$
P(U\le u)=P(F(X)\le u)=P(X\le F^{-1}(u))=F(F^{-1}(u))=u,\mbox{ for }u\in[0,1].
$$
It is also well known that $-\ln(U)$ has Exponential distribution.